# Laravel validate model

Tags: php, forms, validation, model, laravel-4

I've created an `Employer` model in my Laravel 4 application and, in `Employer.php` I have created the following function to validate user input before saving it to the database:

```
public static function validate($input)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($input, static::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails() {
        return $validator;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This works fine when I'm creating a new record in the database, because I am passing in values for all the rules where I have specified a particular field is required.

However, there are certain fields in the database I don't want the user to edit after they have been created (for example, `business_name`). On the controller's edit method I create a form and omit those fields from the form. But validation fails because `business_name` is required by the `$rules`.

As a temporary work around, I tried just creating a hidden field in the edit form and populating it with the `business_name`. However, this is also required to be unique and fails when I PATCH my form to the `update` method!

Any advice? Is there any way I can specify which validation rules should be applied depending on the method calling it? Or should I create a new method in `Employer.php` specifically to validate on the update method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `required_without` validation rule. Since an newly instantiated model doesn't have an id field yet, you can require some fields only when `id` is not present. This should work:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'business_name' => 'required_without:id'
);
```

http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-required-without

Comment: Thanks - are there any other alternatives though? I'm thinking perhaps in a situation where I might want to have separate edit forms for a model that might have a large number of fields, instead of them all being on one page. Or is this considered poor practice?

Comment: In that case you might want to define multiple rule sets for each form and use them accordingly in your `validate` method. But if there are a lot of fields you should be able to group some of them into subsets and use them as separate entities.